# Bitbucket - Working on reverted merged pull request and creating new Pull request for same branch

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, pull-request

I recently moved from SVN to Git/Bitbucket and working on code that is maintained in Bitbucket.
I am looking for solution to work on reverted merged pull request-

Background scenario: I have Branch-A in which I have modified 6 existing java files, checked-in these files in Branch-A and created PullRequest-A and merged it into master. But, my team mate reverted my merged pull request and asked me to add few loggers in those 6 files.
As a result of reverting the merged pull request(PullRequest-A) of Branch-A, a new branch named "Revert-Branch-A is automatically created in bitbucket . This "Revert-Branch-A" does not have my modified changes which I made in Branch-A.

My questions are as below :-

Question 1:-  Since I have to add loggers to those modified 6 files, in which branch should I work on? Is it the original "Branch-A" or new "Revert-Branch-A" .

Question 2:-  What to do with the new branch "Revert-Branch-A" , in case I have to work on "Branch-A" itself .

I explored few solutions, like revert the revert , but I am not sure how it is done in bitbucket as it doesn't show me option for "reverting the revert" . Also, referred to the below official Atlassian bitbucket doc, but it doesn't mention how to proceed after reverting the merged pull request.
[https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/merge-a-pull-request-945541513.html#Mergeapullrequest-Revertamergedpullrequest][1]

Any help with would be of great appreciation!

Thanks,
Divya